# How to make dynamic API

Tags: php

I am trying to make a simple API, that will grab data on specific request.

Let say I have a URL:

`https://mywebsite.com/api/cars/brand`

My `.htaccess` looks like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/cars/([^/]+)/? api/cars.php?brand=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So when i enter the url `https://mywebsite.com/api/cars/audi`

Im getting response which looks like that:

`array(1) { ["brand"]=> string(4) "audi" }`

Which is OK, but the problem is if I want to have more variables.

For example: `https://mywebsite.com/api/cars/audi/a8/silver/2004`

Which should look like that:

`array(2) { ["brand"]=> string(4) "audi" ["model"]=> string(2) "a8"} etc..`

I also want to be able to print single param:

`https://mywebsite.com/api/cars/audi/red/`

And I don't really know how to make it work, as I can't rewriteRules like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/cars/([^/]+)/? api/cars.php?brand=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/cars/([^/]+)/([^/]+)? api/cars.php?brand=$1&model=$2 [L,QSA]
```

And I feel also it is not a good way of doing it. Any tips, hints, examples?

Comment: in rest, you wouldn't make them part of the url, instead use parameters i.e `?brand=audi&model=a8`, your endpoint should simply be `/api/cars` for POST/DELETE/PUT you would use an id `/api/cars/:id`, 2 routes not 4*n params

Comment: I will be more complicated than i thought

Comment: No its much simpler. `[GET: /api/cars?brand=audi&model=a8]` / `[POST: /api/cars]` / `[PUT: /api/cars/:id]` / `[DELETE: /api/cars/:id]`. Also dont do any routing in .htaccess do it in the app. Your rewrite should look like `RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]`.. check out how micro frameworks do it.

Comment: Could you show me your idea more specific? Code a bit if possible. Edit: Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data in mySql table to get response in json using php.
make a get request to your url with id of your brand
eg:

```
https://mywebsite.com/api/cars/brand?id=1
```

This will return all cars with brand id=1 

Same way you can create muliple API's

Comment: His problem isn't how to look up the data, but how to rewrite the URL to get the components into the correct parameters.

Comment: He said "And I feel also it is not a good way of doing it. Any tips, hints, examples?"